# Spring Listen Context Initialization Completion

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How to call a spring controller after all the bean get initialized?

I used `ServletContextListener` and tried to call one controller. But, it doesn't exixts since all the bean initialization are getting invoked after the `contextInitialized` method execution.

I'm loading one variable from db, in the application context which has some global value. That action has to be triggered once the application is deployed immediately.

What needs to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved my requirement using below code:

```
@WebListener
public class StartUpListener implements ServletContextListener {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(StartUpListener.class);

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        logger.info("********* context Refreshed **********");

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run(){
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
                    URL url = new URL ("http://localhost:8080/myapp/loadFeature");
                    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                    String inputLine;
                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        logger.info(inputLine);
                    }
                    in.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error(e);
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        logger.info("********* context contextDestroyed **********");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@PostConstruct` phase to simulate context initialization completion.

I assume you want to invoke methods on `ControllerA`, `ControllerB` and store the results of those method invocations elsewhere on app start up.

```
public class InitializationHook {
    private ControllerA controllerA;
    private ControllerB controllerB;

    @Autowired
    public InitializationHook(ControllerA controllerA, ControllerB controllerB) {
        this.controllerA = controllerA;
        this.controllerB = controllerB;
}

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        //do whatever you want with both the controllers
        controllerA.getGlobalValueFromDB();
        controllerB.doSomethingElse();
        /*
        * At this point, controllerA and controllerB would have been initialized completely 
        * along with their dependencies (could be connections to DB etc) and ready for use. 
        * You don't have to worry about the other beans getting initialized. 
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: Will it get invoked every time? I want only once the action has to be called automatically. Currently I'm calling that action by hitting the URL. Same action has to be triggered once all the bean initialization is completed.

Comment: This will be called only once during the lifetime of your application. Can you give a reason as to why this has to be called once all the beans initialization is completed? Is there a logical reason for this? I assumed the reason was you were not able to invoke ControllerA properly before all the beans initialized.

Comment: I have a map in the `applicationContext` which has few values which will be used across the application. Those values are maintained in db. Instead of checking the values every time logging in, I'm maintaining it in the context. Whenever there is a modification in those db value, I'm overriding the context during the update operation.

Comment: Hi dude. I tried it just now. `@PostConstruct` is not working. Initialization starts after the post construct log printed. Any other possibility?

Comment: This `@PostConstruct` will run after `ControllerA` and `ControllerB` are completely initialized. There is no straightforward way to hook into initialization complete phase. Because that is vague. Some beans might be initialized on demand. Please update the question stating what exactly you need with some code. You are saying initialization starts after postConstruct. Please post the code of whose initialization you are seeing.

Comment: My straightforward question is, I have the URL, `http://localhost:8080/myapp/loadappcontext`, I want to trigger this URL once the server is started. While I hit the URL in the listener/ post construct, it gives exception since, after postconstruct log only all the requestMapping path are getting initialized during the server startup. Currently I'm triggering this URL once the server is up and running.

Comment: My answer is based on hitting the controller directly. Can you not hit the controller directly by method invocation?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to execute some piece of code exactly before the application startup completes, you can [CommandLineRunner](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner.html).

```
@Component
public class ControllerRunner implements  CommandLineRunner {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ControllerRunner.class);

    @Override
    public void run(String...args) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Your application has been started");
        //TODO - call your controller
    }
}
```